# Best-case performance of disjoint set forests, and proving lower bounds of algorithms

Tags: data-structures, theory, adt, disjoint-sets

There is a question on an assignment that was due today which solutions have been released for, and I don't understand the correct answer. The question deals with best-case performance of disjoint sets in the form of [disjoint set forests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#Disjoint-set_forests) that utilize the weighed union algorithm to improve performance (the smaller of the trees has its root connected as a child to the root of the larger of the two trees) but **without** using the path compression algorithm.

The question is whether the best case performance of doing (n-1) Union operations on n singleton nodes and m>=n Find operations in any order is Omega(m*logn) which the solution confirms is correct like this:

> There is a sequence S of n-1 Unions followed by m >= n Finds that takes Omega(m log n) time. The sequence S starts with a sequence n-1 Unions that builds a tree with depth Omega(log n).  Then it has m>=n Finds, each one for the deepest leaf of that tree, so each one takes 
>   (log n) time.

My question is, why does that prove the lower bound is Omega(m*logn) is correct? Isn't that just an isolated example of when the bound would be Omega(m*logn) that doesn't prove it for *all* inputs? I am certain one needs to only show one counter-example when disproving a claim but needs to prove a predicate for *all* possible inputs in order to prove its correctness.

In my answer, I pointed out the fact that you could have a case when you start off by joining two singleton nodes together. You then join in another singleton to that 2-node tree with 3 nodes sharing the same parent, then another etc., until you join together all the n nodes. You then have a tree where n-1 nodes all point up to the same parent, which is essentially the result you obtain if you use path compression. Then every FIND is executed in O(1) time. Thus, a sequence of (n-1) Unions and m>=n Finds ends up being Omega(n-1+m) = Omega(n+m) = Omega(m).

Doesn't this imply that the Omega(m*logn) bound is not tight and the claim is, therefore, incorrect? I'm starting to wonder if I don't fully understand Big-O/Omega/Theta :/

EDIT : fixed up the question to be a little clearer

EDIT2: Here is the [original question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoCz0.png) the way it was presented and the [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzg5S.png) (it took me a little while to realize that Gambarino and the other guy are completely made up; hardcore Italian prof)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like I indeed misunderstood the concept of Big-Omega. For some strange reason, I presumed Big-Omega to be equivalent to "what's the input into the function that results in the best possible performance". In reality, most likely unsurprisingly to the reader but a revelation to me, Big-Omega simply describes the lower bound of a function. That's it. Therefore, a worst case input will have a lower and upper bounds (big-O and omega), and so will the best possible input. In case of big-omega here, all we had to do was come up with a scenario where we pick the 'best' input given the limitations of the worst case, i.e. that there is *some* input of size n that will take the algorithm *at least* m*logn steps. If such input exists, then the lower bound is tight.

Comment: An even easier way to think about it: it's the 'worst of the worst' case, i.e. the worst possible input that causes the algorithm to do the most amount of work.